# "File not found" when using np.random.choice() to select files to move from listdir() result

Tags: python

I'm trying to sample 10k samples from a folder that contains images. Following is the code i used:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil

ori_path = "D:\\LSUN\\lsun-master\\train_data_bedroom"
des_path = "D:\\LSUN\\lsun-master\\Train\\bedroom"
# list all files in dir
files = os.listdir(ori_path)

# select 10k of the files randomly 
random_files = np.random.choice(files, 10000)

#renaming index
ii = 1

for x in random_files:
    src = os.path.join(ori_path,x)
    des = os.path.join(des_path,str(ii)+".png")
    shutil.move(src,des)
    ii+=1
```

When i run this code, i always get this error after copying several images

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\LSUN\\lsun-master\\train_data_bedroom\\120c22c9525271d7041ed7883a23323cf53f67c8.png'
```

Then i went back to my source folder and search for this file and I found there is no such file.

So my question is, how would listdir find a file that does not exist in the folder? And How should i fix this?

Comment: What happens when the same file is randomly chosen twice? (The first time, it gets moved; the second time, it's not there any longer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `np.random.choice()` is a random choice *with replacement*, meaning the same value can be chosen twice (the idea is that once chosen, it's put back in the metaphorical bucket from which an item is randomly selected).

This means the same *file* can be chosen twice, but of course once you moved a file, it's not there any longer and so your code will fail if it's chosen again.

Pass `replace=False` to turn off replacement, so each file can be chosen only once:

```
random_files = np.random.choice(files, min(len(files), 10000), replace=False)
```

Comment: thank you, I can't believe i thought i used shutil.copy the whole time. Now it works perfectly now!

Comment: If the issue is addressed, you can use the checkbox next to an answer to accept it, and thereby mark your question solved.